# "mock app" how to search through a database for matches? (react-native app)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend, backend

Im working on a mock app as a project to have for my portfolio as a frontend developer.
So far i've been able to  fairly accurately mock some posts requests in my app ( requests for fetching data, logging in, etc ) here is an example of my login func

```
export const loginUser = async ({
  username,
  password,
  onSuccess = () => {},
  onFailure = () => {},
}) =>
  postReq({
    endpoint: LOGIN_USER,
    body: {
      username,
      password,
    },
    onSuccess,
    onFailure,
  });
```

all of my "Data" lives in a json file in my project file.
however not very familiar with the backend side of things,  How would the backend normally perform a search that returns data ? and whats the closest thing i can do from the frontend?  I've only recently discovered regular expression functions, is this a path in the right direction? Thank you very much, Im excited to keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using redux or useReducer kind of logic to handle your login. This seems fairly true what you did for authenticate user from frontend side.

For backend side;

1- You send your request(via axios, fetch, ajax etc) to your server(backend) like this and waiting for a response.

2- You are taking this information from your request body as you send this informations in your request body which is the preferred way.

3- You check for username in your database if there is a collasion, you will check for password correctness which i advice you to store your passwords hashed and check correctness via hash compare.

4-If there is no collasion or password is not correct you  send an error with relative status code like 500 and a message "A user with
the given username and password could not be found"

5- If password is true, you send your feedback your frontend with a success status response(like 200).

6- You taking your response from your server and take the necessary actions accordingly

And keep up your passion you will have a lot of fun

Comment: cool thank you very much.  Yes thats exactly what I do (= I send back the status, message and data in the payload.  however for userLogin its easy because the characters must match exactly,  but what about an endpoint that gets used in a search bar for my app? in a real world app would regex be used?

Comment: that is depend on your database and your search algorithm. if you want a complex search logic you will have to write your own algorithm based on your query language(like sql). in this case basic regex(if your database support) won't be enough. if you want simple searching algorithm like is this word 'foo' includes on any column in any row in a table i want(for ex. in people table which row's column named 'Name' includes 'John'), you may want to do this queries case insensitive and most databases are case sensitive so you will have some options there. you can search for them when you get there.